# Canvas fillStyle performance

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was checking how much less my game was going to perform with a trail effect. But what I noticed was that I got more operations per second. How is this possible?

How is this...

```
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500); // clearing canvas without any trail effect
```

... slower than this?

```
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'; // clearing canvas with trail effect
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
```

**Link to test:** http://jsperf.com/canvas-trailing-effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is a little initialization issue here : The canvas fillstyle is not reseted between each test loop.

Setup the fillstyle before calling fillRect, and you'll see that a fillRect with black color is faster, as expected.

Also remember that clearRect will be faster to clear the canvas.

i updated your performance test :

http://jsperf.com/canvas-trailing-effect/2

Edit : i was curious to know the overhead of several calls, so i edited the performance test
to see the time taken in 3 / 10 / 20 steps.

so we have, on FF (mac OS / imac) :

3 steps :   1/12000 = 83 ns   = 3  * overhead + filltime
  10 steps :  1/8000  = 125 ns  = 10 * overhead + filltime
  20 steps :  1/5000  = 200 ns  = 20 * overhead + filltime

so we have an overhead near 6 ns, with a filltime near 60 ns.

So the formula is approximately time taken = number of steps * 6 + (ratio filled) * 60
which makes 90 ns for 50% fill in ten steps.

This kind of computation should be done on several browsers / devices to be more relevant.

Also this test would benefit from being done within a rAF.

Comment: Thank you! That explains it :) How about clearing just parts of the canvas. Example: a rectangle moving around - would it be better to add this effect to it than the whole canvas? Or would it be just the same?

Comment: You're welcome. Hard to have a definitive answer : with just one smaller rect, you'll be faster of course, but with many draw operations, depending on the canvas implementation overhead it might be slower (especially with slow devices). Also think about calling this kind of operation within a requestAnimationFrame callback, since some implementations only draw in sync (which is quite logical).